# A type of PDE equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am asking if there is a formula for the general solution $f$ of a PDE of the form:

$$h(x,y)(∂f(x,y)/∂x)+g(x,y)f(x,y)+w(x,y)=0$$
$$h(x,y)(∂f(x,y)/∂y)+g(x,y)f(x,y)+w(x,y)=0$$

where $h,g,w$ are smooth functions in $x>0,y>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIRST EQUATION :
$$h(x,y)\frac{∂f(x,y)}{∂x}+g(x,y)f(x,y)+w(x,y)=0 \tag 1$$
Since there is only a derivative with respect to one variable $x$, the equation $(1)$ is not a PDE , but is an ODE. In this ODE $y$ is a simple parameter. Thus, solve the first order linear ODE :
$$h(x)\frac{dF}{dx}+g(x)F(x)+w(x)=0$$
while $y$ is considered as a parameter exactly like any other parameter existing in Eq.$(1)$.

You will find the solution on the form $f(x)=F(x,c)$ in which $c$ is an arbitray constant of integration.

The parameter $y$ will appear in your result : 
$$f(x,y)=F(x,y,c(y))$$
in which $F(x,y, c(y))$ is known now. The function $c(y)$ is arbitrary.

SECOND EQUATION :
$$h(x,y)\frac{∂f(x,y)}{∂y}+g(x,y)f(x,y)+w(x,y)=0 \tag 2$$
Since there is only a derivative with respect to one variable $y$, the equation $(1)$ is not a PDE , but is an ODE. In this ODE $y$ is a simple parameter. Thus, solve the first order linear ODE :
$$h(y)\frac{dG}{dy}+g(y)G(y)+w(y)=0$$
while $x$ is considered as a parameter exactly like any other parameter existing in Eq.$(2)$.

You will find the solution on the form $f(y)=G(y,C)$ in which $C$ is an arbitrary constant of integration.

The parameter $x$ will appear in your result :
$$f(x,y)=G(y,x,C(x))$$
in which $G(y,x,C(x))$ is known now. The function $C(x)$ is arbitrary.

SUPPOSING

that the problem is to find the solutions $f(x,y)$ which satisfy simultaneously both ODEs $(1)$ and $(2)$, in the general case there is no solution because $F(x,y,c(y))$ and $G(y,x,C(x))$ are not necessarily equal.

But depending on $h(x,y)$, $g(x,y)$ , $w(x,y)$ and depending on boundary conditions, $F(x,y,c(y))$ and $g(y,x,C(x))$ might be equal in particular cases. In these particular cases the equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ have a common solution.

One cannot say more because the problem is too general. For more specific comment the functions $h(x,y), g(x,y), w(x,y)$ should be defined.